# Creating table with multiple row and column names

Tags: matlab, names

I'm trying to create a table in matlab, with rows and columns which have several 'levels' of names, par example column name 'Neutral' which is divided into sublevels 'M' and 'SD' (see below for an illustration). I have the same problem with rows. Does anyone know if this is possible in Matlab, and if yes, how?

```
| Neutral |<- Column name
|----|----|
| M  | SD |<- Sublevel of column name
|----|----|
|5.70|2.39|<- Data
|7.37|2.27|<- 
| .. | .. |<-
| .. | .. |<-
```

Comment: This is not possible to do while still maintaining the ability to natively index the columns.

Comment: Do you really need Matlab for this? Excel (or another spreadsheet program) may be better suited for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest `table` objects, like so:

```
t = table(table((1:10)', rand(10,1), 'VariableNames', {'M', 'SD'}), ...
    'VariableNames', {'Neutral'});
```

The display looks a little odd, but you can index the nested variables in the way that you might expect, i.e. `t.Neutral.M` etc.